# Finding one word or another in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to MongoDB so I was wondering how do you search a document for one word or another especially if one word is phrase and another is single word.

Here if we have to search word printer or ink, we use the syntax below.

```
db.supplies.runCommand("text", {search:"printer ink"})
```

What do I do if I want to find word "printer ink" or paper? Notice how Printer ink is a phrase. I tried

```
db.supplies.runCommand("text", {search:"\"printerink\" paper"})
```

but it didn't help so I am hoping someone could help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting the documentation

> If the $search string includes a phrase and individual terms, text search will only match the documents that include the phrase. More specifically, the search performs a logical AND of the phrase with the individual terms in the search string

That being said to find word `printer ink` or `paper` you will need to run two different queries

```js
db.supplies.find({ $text: { $search: "\"printer ink\"" }})
```

and

```js
db.supplies.find({ $text: { $search: "paper" }})
```

Instead you can use [**`$regex`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#regex) operator if the task doesn't required the use of `$text`

```js
db.supplies.find({ <yourfield>: {"$in": [/printer ink/, /paper/] }})
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I was just wondering if we had another way to do it. So once we get these we do union between them right?

Comment: @Sam no there is no other way since  query can specify, at most, one `$text` expression

Comment: I just verified this using `.find({$text:{$search:'/(\"printer ink\")|(paper)/'}})` and it does indeed only match the phrase, regardless of the order in the regex. Imagine that.